# UIButton within UITableViewCell is Tappable(Getting proper event) But the issue is tap effect is not visible

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a custom table view cell with UILable and UIButton which is working fine I am getting proper event on button tap, but the issue is tap effect of button is not visible in UI.

Edit -  Functionality wise button is working fine but the issue is that on tap, tap effect is not visible see below attached image.

[image]

I am expecting below same smooth touch for button which is within tableview Cell -

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your problem little more?

Comment: Please check attached image..hope you understand my problem.

Comment: What is your buttons type? `custom` or `system`?

Comment: custom and I want it to be custom only.

Answer (score 3):

add this on your button `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` and check once

```
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = TRUE
```

Comment: This is not a solution for which I am looking. I don't  want to use Highlighted or selected properties for that..

Comment: @PremaJanoti - I know this is not the excat answer , it is one of the way to find the solution

Comment: yes!! That I know but my requirement is different :)

Comment: @PremaJanoti - lets we go  step by step , are you tried my answer it is working or not

Comment: @PremaJanoti - info is the UImage of text with background color

Comment: yes it is working but it is giving spark effect which i don't want.. And I am using background color not image.

Comment: @PremaJanoti - good , it means working, can you show the code button related code

Comment: within `awakeFromNib` method I added this line..
        btnInfo.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true

Comment: @PremaJanoti - no no I am not asked that , my code is working fine , based on your requirment we need to follow, so show ur code for related to uibutton

Comment: I don't have any code which is written for button's UI.. I have only IBAction for that button and within that button i am calling a method which will show guest info screen.

Comment: you mean storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Text Color` e.g Light Gray Color for the button's highlighted state in storyboard.

[image]

It will give a tap effect to your button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't  want to use Highlighted or selected properties for that. That I know how to use these properties.

Comment: What kind of tap effect do you exactly want?

Comment: I think you need an Image for the button for that kind of tap effect.